# How to show Assembled Ant Classpath

Tags: ant, classpath

I'm developing a Java project using Eclipse, and Ant as a build tool. When I run "ant all" from the command line, my project builds without any errors, but on Eclipse I get many compilation errors.

So I thought I'd copy Ant's Classpath onto my Eclipse Project's Build Path.

Is there an Ant task/command to show that? Like "ant just show me your assembled classpath" or something?

Answer (score 5):

If you run Ant with the -verbose and -debug flags, you'll see all gory details of what javac is doing, including the classpath.

Comment: If using those switches better also use `-l antLogFile.log`, otherwise all the __gory details__ will easily fill up all screen without giving any change to understand the output. Also the javac task can also received a `verbose=true` which will show the actual classpath being used for compilation, maybe it's better than using ant with verbose (since it will just less data)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was looking for a list of jar files and directories where the Java compiler should look to find classes used for building the application. The classpath.

Comment: With these flags I get something like this:

Comment: Finding class net.sf.antcontrib.walls.CompileWithWalls
Loaded from C:\projects\DmLights\trunk\hybris\bin\platform\lib\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar net/sf/antcontrib/walls/CompileWithWalls.class

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a task for printing the classpath, and call that task with antcall. The classpath would be given as a parameter to that task.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your target, so for example

lets say you've defined your classpath as

```
<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${SERVER_DEV}/classes">
        <include name="*.zip"/>
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${SERVER_DEV}/3rdParty/jre/NT/1.5.0/lib/jsse.jar"/>
</path>
```

then you can do something like

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles All Java Sources">
    <property name="myclasspath" refid="project.classpath"/>
    <echo message="Classpath = ${myclasspath}"/>
    <javac ...>
         ....
    </javac>
</target>
```

It will print out the classpath used to run the specific target